# Is there a way to put local_settings.py to Heroku bypassing Git?

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I'm willing to handle different settings locally and on Heroku. So I use this import at the end of my settings.py:

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

I got local_settings.py locally, not stored in Git. Is there any way to put another local_settings.py to Heroku bypassing Git?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to have specific settings on Heroku is to use environment variables, which you can set via the web interface or `heroku set`, and use them on your settings file to override the defaults like this:

```
MY_SETTING = os.environ.get('MY_ENV_VAR', 'my_default')
```